# How to show back arrow in toolbar in the design editor preview?

Tags: android

I want to see the back arrow (Display home as up etc.) of the toolbar in the design editor preview.

I know in the xml the tools namespace usually has lots of useful things like this, e.g. `tools:listitem` on RecyclerViews etc., is there one for the toolbar to show the back arrow?

Comment: Simply add ``?attr/homeAsUpIndicator``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />
```

Comment: Perfect. Does that have any affect on setting the toolbar as supportActionBar and setting `displayHomeAsUpEnabled` in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can make that feature in java itself instead of xml(Alternative),

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_button_black); //for 
    enabling your own icon.
```

override onoptionsItemSelected Method, for making actions

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed(); //any logic.
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Hi the question was specifically about seeing it in the design editor preview (for design purposes). I know about the above.

Answer (score 0):

To do that

Simply add `?attr/homeAsUpIndicator`

And you'd definitely see the back arrow